# NodeJS getting response from net socket write

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I'm trying to get a response from specific requests via the `write` function.

I'm connected to an equipment via the `net` module (which is the only way to communicate with it). Currently, I have an `.on('data',function)` to listen to responses from the said equipment. I can send commands via the `write` functions to which I am expecting to receive a line of response. How can I go about doing this?

Current code:

```
server = net.Socket();

// connect to server
server.connect(<port>,<ip>,()=>{
    console.log("Connected to server!");
});

// log data coming from the server
server.on("data",(data)=>{
    console.log(''+data);
});

// send command to server
exports.write = function(command){
    server.write(command+"\r\n");
};
```

This is a working code. Sending a command to the equipment via `server.write` returns a response which right now only appears in Terminal. I'd like to return that response right after the `write` request. Preferably within the `exports.write` function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a `callback` argument to your `exports.write` function can solve your problem.

```
exports.write = function(command, callback){
    server.write(command+"\r\n");
    server.on('data', function (data) {
        //this data is a Buffer object
        callback(null, data)
    });

    server.on('error', function (error) {
        callback(error, null)
    });
};
```

call your `write` function

```
var server = require('./serverFilePath')
server.write('callback works', function(error, data){
    console.log('Received: ' + data)
})
```

Comment: If the callback function varies during the coarse of the application, use
<br>
`server.once('data', callback);`